# How to check whether an element of a character array is empty?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I need to check if an element of a java array of characters is empty. I tried out the following code but didn't work. What's wrong?

```
char c[] = new char[3];
c[0] = 'd';

for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if(c[i] == null) {
        System.out.println(i + " is empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: Side issue: `char[] c` is generally preferred over `char c[]` as it keeps all the type information in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take arrays out of the equation - an array is just a collection of variables, really. Let's consider a single variable. Suppose we had a method like this:

```
public boolean isEmpty(char c)
```

What would that do? The value of `c` cannot be `null`, because `char` is a primitive type. It could be U+0000 (aka `'\u0000'` or `'\0'` as character literals in Java), and that's the default value of `char` (for array elements and fields) but it's not the same as a null reference.

If you want a type which is like `char` but is a reference type, you should consider using [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) - the wrapper type for `char` just like `Integer` is for `int`. Or if you know that you'll *never* use U+0000 as a valid value, you could just stick with that.

However, a better alternative would often be to design your code so that you don't *need* the concept of "empty or not empty". We don't know what you're trying to achieve here, but it's usually a good thing to at least consider. For arrays, the alternative is often to use an `ArrayList<E>` - but of course you can't have an `ArrayList<char>` in Java as Java generics don't allow primitive type arguments :(

Comment: Best answer. Just what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

An element of a primitive array can't be null. It will always have a default value if you didn't initialize it yourself. The default for char is 0.

Comment: What should I do for this then?

Comment: @xXLemonProgrammerXx That depends whether the default value 0 can be a valid value in your code. If it can't, you can simply check `if (c[i] > 0)`. If `0` is a valid value, you can use the boxed version - Character - which can be null. Or you can use an int array instead of char array, and initialize the elements of the array to -1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Character` class instead primitive `char`.

```
Character c[] = new Character[3];
c[0] = 'd';

for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    if(c[i] == null){
        System.out.println(i + " is empty");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `null` as `char` is a primitive type. `null` only works for objects. use `\0` as it's the primitive version of null.

Answer (score 0):

primitive char's default value is 0. you can check it with 0
    char c[] = new char[3];
    c[0] = 'd';

```
for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    if(c[i] == 0){
        System.out.println(i + " is empty");
    }
}
```

even, char=0 is also a character

Answer (score 0):

Is your code compiling? 
You should be seeing an error message at this code line if(c[i] == null)

And from error message, compiler is clearly revealing that "the operator == is undefined for argument type(s) char,null".

This should suffice that element of a primitive array (character array in this case)can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

Replace null with '\0' with the quotes

Comment: It's technically correct but this answer would benefit from an example. Also, a similar answer already exists so you are not adding anything fresh.Thank you for answering and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know as I got the answer from here last year, but sent link to friend and he didn't get it so i tried to facilitate it and right the answer directly in the simplest way , Thanks.